# How to get list of NGINX VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute in K8S?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Below is the example to add Virtual Server and VirtualServerRoute in kubernetes-ingress.

```html
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: virtualserver
spec:
  host: localhost
  routes:
  - path: /
    route: virtualserverroute
---
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServerRoute
metadata:
  name: virtualserverroute
spec:
  host: localhost
  upstreams:
  - name: proxy
    service: proxy
    port: 80
  - name: webserverv1
    service: webserverv1
    port: 80
  - name: webserverv2
    service: webserverv2
    port: 80
  subroutes:
  - path: /webserverv1
    action:
      pass: webserverv1
  - path: /webserverv2
    action:
      pass: webserverv2
  - path: /
    action:
      pass: proxy
```

Anyone knows How to get list of NGINX VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute for that ingress in K8S?

Comment: Could you tell more specifically what exactly are you trying to list? `VirtualServer` is an alternative for an `Ingress` resource as stated here: [Docs.nginx.com: Nginx-ingress: VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/). Do you mean to `kubectl get virtualserver`?

Comment: yes, i was looking for kubectl get virtualserver and kubectl get virtualserverroutes. Thanks

Comment: Actually, In one of my cluster CRD for nginx VirtualServer and VirtualServerRouts was not added thats why i'm not able to add/get virtualserver.

Answer (score 2):

> Anyone knows How to get list of NGINX VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute for that ingress in K8S?

You can list resources like `VirtualServer` and `VirtualServerRoute` by invoking below command:

- `$ kubectl get VirtualServer` or `kubectl get vs`
- `$ kubectl get VirtualServerRoute` or `kubectl get vsr`

**Please have in mind that above resources are `Custom Resources` and they should be added to Kubernetes.**

---

`VirtualServer` as well as `VirtualServerRoute` are connected **specifically** to the Nginx Ingress Controller created by NginxInc.

Github link:  [Nginxinc: Kubernetes Ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress)

As said on the Github site:

> Note: this project is **different** from the NGINX Ingress controller in [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) repo. See [this doc](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md) to find out about the key differences.
>
> *[Github.com: Nginxinc: Kubernetes Ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress)*

To be able to create:

- `VirtualServer`
- `VirtualServerRoute`

resources you will need to follow [this documentation](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress#getting-started).

If you are using the manifests with `git` please make sure that you apply following manifests:

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f common/vs-definition.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f common/vsr-definition.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f common/ts-definition.yaml
```

As they are `CRD's` for above resources.

After successful provisioning of `nginx-ingress` you should be able to create `VirtualServer` and `VirtualServerRoute` and get more information about them with:

- `kubectl describe vs`
- `kubectl describe vsr`